# Coda Snippet Sync

Tags: code-snippets, coda

I've been trying to rack my head around making a coda plugin for syncing coda's clips to snipplr.com, coda is such a great app, but the inability to sync my hand crafted snippets is really irritating especially when you are out and about with a laptop!

I was wondering if anyone has any experience in developing such a plugin, or even had any success with syncing snippets across computers?

Hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is doable at this time...

I wanted to do the same but it looks like the clips are stored in this (binary?) file: /Applications/Coda.app/Contents/MacOS/Coda

The Panic team will have to create an altenate location for this and also the sites database... it would be really nice if we could sync all our settings/sites/connections/clips and sync them via [dropbox](http://shennyg.com/b/dropbox)

let's not hold our breath... try my recommendation for [syncing snippets/clips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101/where-do-you-store-your-code-snippets/2944840#2944840):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101/where-do-you-store-your-code-snippets/2944840#2944840

Comment: thanks, i had a look at snippets its a really nice app, although i have enough menu bar apps moment. Thanks for the suggestion though :) +1 (Lets hope for coda 2.0 soon!)

Comment: I agree on having way too many menu bar items... but FYI you can turn that off in the preferences. Doing that disables the hotkeys (dealbreaker?).

Cannot wait for what the panic boys have in store for us with Coda 2.

Comment: mmm, i'm still tempted to wait for what panic has in store. No doubt it will be amazing! Thanks for all your help though! I would +2 you if i could :(

Answer (score 0):

Combining information I found here on where Clips are stored: https://github.com/bobthecow/codaclips/pull/1#issuecomment-6023192

```
~/Library/Application Support/Coda 2/
```

With how to make a symlink:

```
ln -s /Users/[username]/Google\ Drive/Clips /Users/[username]/Library/Application\ Support/Coda\ 2
```

You could replace the path to Google Drive to other services such as Dropbox as well. Just symlink it.

Thats how I sync my clips across computers. Hopefully that helps someone else. Note: this will sync all clips, not just specific groupings. You could apply the same logic to Sites and other settings as well if you wanted.